# How to map values of JavaFX observables?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `SimpleIntegerProperty` and want to derive a `SimpleObjectProperty<Color>` from it. 

For that I imagine some mechanism like with streams and optionals:

```
SimpleIntegerProperty intProp;
ObjectProperty<Color> colorProp = intProp.map(i -> convertIntToColor(i), c -> convertColorToInt(c));
```

Is there something built-in already or do I really need to roll this out on my own? 

It would seems odd if there is no such thing because looking at all the power of `Bindings` gives you the strong feeling that this feature should also be there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unsure if this is the best way, but this seems to work using `Bindings.createObjectBinding`:

```
@Test
    public void test() {
        SimpleIntegerProperty simpleIntegerProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
        ObjectBinding<Color> binding = Bindings
                .createObjectBinding(() -> converToColor(simpleIntegerProperty.get()), simpleIntegerProperty);
        System.out.println(binding.get());
        binding.addListener(new ChangeListener<Color>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Color> observable, Color oldValue, Color newValue) {
                System.out.println(newValue);
            }
        });
        simpleIntegerProperty.set(2);
    }

    private Color converToColor(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                return Color.RED;
            case 2:
                return Color.BLUE;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Wim's answer is the best way to do this if you want to use only the standard JavaFX libraries. If you are happy to add third-party libraries to the project, Tomas Mikula's [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) (version 2.0 or later) provides this functionality out of the box:

```
IntegerProperty rgba = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
Property<Color> color = Var.mapBidirectional(rgba.asObject(),
    this::convertIntToColor, this::convertColorToInt);

// ...

private Color convertIntToColor(Integer rgba) {
    // ...
}

private Integer convertColorToInt(Color c) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I kinda like this, but this library doesn't seem "production ready" by any means, and I don't see any recent commits to the project either, so definitely nothing we can use here :(.

Comment: The history is that he rolled functionality from another project, [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) into his reactive event streams implementation. EasyBind was initially written as a proof-of-concept for a [JavaFX feature request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091544). While that feature request is still officially slated for JDK9, it's currently unresolved so I doubt it'll be there.  So, yes, I get your point. Of course, the source code is all available, so if you like it enough you could just roll the essential parts into your own implementation :).

Answer (score 0):

It took them long enough, but **JavaFX 19** *finally* has this built into [ObservableValue](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#map(java.util.function.Function)), it seems (which many of the classes mentioned in this question and answers implement):

> `default <U> ObservableValue<U> map(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)`
>
> Returns an `ObservableValue` that holds the result of applying the given mapping function on this value. The result is updated when this `ObservableValue` changes. If this value is `null`, no mapping is applied and the resulting value is also `null`.

It's an `ObservableValue`, not an `ObjectProperty` or `ObjectBinding`, but hopefully sufficient.

Methods `orElse(T constant)` and `flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends ObservableValue<? extends U>> mapper)` were also added in this release.

---

You can find the original ticket [here](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274771) and other JavaFX 19 release notes [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/openjfx-19-release-notes/).